# Open Multidatepicker on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

When I try to hide an input containing the dates selected by the user with :

```
style = "display:none"
```

The picker does display anymore.
I absolutely need to hide this input since the only thing the user must see is the button he clicks to open the picker.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Répercuter" class="button" id="btnRepercute"/>
<input type="text" name="dateMultiCalendar_1" id="dateMultiCalendar_1" class="dateMultiCalendar_1"/>
```

JS:

```
$('#dateMultiCalendar_1').multiDatesPicker($.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ]);
$('#btnRepercute').click(function() {
$("#dateMultiCalendar_1").datepicker( "destroy" );
$('#dateMultiCalendar_1').multiDatesPicker
({

           // $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ]
           //beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
         var today = new Date();
           if (date.getDay() === 1 || date.getDay() === 2 || date.getDay() === 3
           || date.getDay() === 4 || date.getDay() === 5)

           {
            if (date.getMonth() === today.getMonth())
                {
                    return [true, ''];
                }
           }
        return [false, ''];
        }

});
 $('#dateMultiCalendar_1').focus();
});
```

I just noticed that when I click on the button to display the picker, the calendar always displays under the input and never under the button. Maybe the reason why when I hide the input, the calendar no longer appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you cannot give focus to a non-displayed field.
However you can display the date picker from javascript using `datepicker('show')`.
(Not that in this instance we use datepicker and not multiDatesPicker)

Try this :

```
//Attach the date picker to you text field
$('#dateMultiCalendar_1').multiDatesPicker({
           beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var today = new Date();
                if (date.getDay() >= 1 && date.getDay() <= 5){
                   if (date.getMonth() === today.getMonth(){
                      return [true, ''];
                   }
                }
                return [false, ''];
           }
 });

//Make the button display the date picker on cick
$('#btnRepercute').click(function() {
         $('#dateMultiCalendar_1').datepicker('show');
});
```

Comment: Thx a lot for sharing yout knowledge

Answer (score 0):

[updated]

```
$('#dateMultiCalendar_1').hide();
$('#dateMultiCalendar_1').datepicker({
           // $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ]
           //beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var today = new Date();
    if (date.getDay() >= 1 && date.getDay() <= 5)
    {
       if (date.getMonth() === today.getMonth())
          {
              return [true, ''];
          }
       }
       return [false, ''];
     },
  showOn: "button"
});
$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').text('whatever');
```

Sorry I couldn't get back to you in time, but it seems that you got your answer already, here would be mine anyways:

```
$('#dateMultiCalendar_1').hide();
$('#dateMultiCalendar_1').multiDatesPicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        if (date.getDay() >= 1 && date.getDay() <= 5)
            return [true, ''];
        else
            return [false, ''];
     }
});

$('#btnRepercute').click(function(){
    $('#dateMultiCalendar_1').toggle('show');
});
```

and here is the fiddle : [click me](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/RMUjQ/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help but the multidatepicker always closes when i select a date!